# Hazelcast: is Index on query Cache required?

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Short code example:

```
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);

IMap<Integer, Integer> clientMap = client.getMap(mapName);
clientMap.addIndex("user.id", false);

QueryCache<Integer, Integer> cache = clientMap.getQueryCache(cacheName);
cache.addIndex("user.id", false);
```

Should the index be add to cache and IMap or just at one of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index is not required on the `QueryCache` or the backing `IMap` but depending on your use case an index may help with your solution's performance. For example:

- An index on the map may improve the time taken to initially populate the `QueryCache`, if the query cache's `Predicate` can take advantage of the index. You can take a look at [this trivial benchmark](https://github.com/vbekiaris/map-querycache-bench) to compare the time taken to initialize a `QueryCache` (on my local when the map is indexed, initial query cache population is several orders of magnitude faster but obviously YMMV).
- If your use case involves filtering the query cache (eg via `QueryCache.values(Predicate)`) then an index on the `QueryCache` would help speed up your queries. Still, consider that this is done at the expense of more expensive writes in the `QueryCache` due to the overhead of index maintenance.